# free memory malloc MPI

Tags: c, mpi, calloc

What is the best way to free memory allocated before calling mpi init? In the code given below should the calloced memory deallocated before mpi finalize or after mpi finalize. Anyhow doing either way does not give any errors.

Thanks

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int   hostid, numprocessors;
    int *trial;
    trial = calloc(5,sizeof(int));
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocessors);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&hostid);
    free(trial);
    MPI_Finalize();
    //free(trial);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: So what's the question? Is this memory supposed to be used?

Comment: If you don't make the memory available to `MPI_Init()`, you can free it whenever suits you.  There might be arguments of 'nesting symmetry' for doing the free after the call to `MPI_Finalize()`, but your code should be fine as it stands.  You may be able to use [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) to validate this.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan and Severin for your replies. The reason I asked this question is that I'm in the process of writing a complex hybrid parallel code that uses openmp, mpi  and gpu for climate model simulations and it would be good to know what should be the standard practice in these scenarios. I did try Valgrind but it was not working for MPI programs on ubuntu ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mpich2/+bug/1045326)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comment into an answer to allow for closure.*</sup>

If you don't make the memory available to `MPI_Init()`, you can free it whenever suits you. There might be arguments of 'nesting symmetry' for doing the free after the call to `MPI_Finalize()`, but your code should be fine as it stands.

Of course, the code in the question doesn't use the allocated memory anywhere.  However, the observations still apply.  As long as you don't free the memory before the last code using it completes, you should be fine.

You may be able to use [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) to validate this *(…though I note the [observation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481833/free-memory-malloc-mpi#comment47125276_29481833) that `valgrind` does not work with MPI programs, at least on the Ubuntu environment which is, presumably, the relevant one…)*.

Comment: In 2019, valgrind works well for MPI (mpich) programs on Ubuntu (Disco).